# Input text, принимающий только числа

Tags: jquery, javascript

> xxx: Добрый вечер. Как сделать, что в
> input можно было вводить только числа?
> yyy: Ну вообще можно так ....код.....
> xxx: Забавный ввод получается.
> Нажимаешь на буквенную клавишу, буква
> появляется и исчезает) А вот чтобы
> вообще не появлялась можно? 
> YYY: Можно - выломайте пользователю все буквы на клавиатуре, чтобы и нажать не смог

Это с баша.

```
<input type="text" id="onlynumbers" />

$('#onlynumbers').keydown(function(event){
    if((event.which<48 && event.which!=8) || event.which>57 || event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Это, что получилось у меня.
Как сделать красивее и улучшить код?
Ну, кроме введения.

```
var BACKSPACE = 8;
var ZERO_CODE = 48;
var NINE_CODE = ZERO_CODE + 9;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zLmtco42/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Года 3 назад откопал в инетах вот эту функцию и использую её:

```
   $(selector).keypress(function (e) {
      if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
         return false;
      }
   });
```

Вот [ваш пример с этой фукнцией](http://jsfiddle.net/zLmtco42/6/)

Comment: 1) return false не рекомендуется) НО вместо него можно поставить prevent default, Это не проблема.
в остальном, да, условие мне нравится немного больше.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

http://jsfiddle.net/xt1Lhr3d/
(Добавил плагин слева как External resource)

Как вариант. А вообще очень много всяких библиотек по теме есть.

Comment: Ну да... но мне бы хотелось понять, КАК оно написано.

Comment: https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/numeric/jquery.numeric.js

вот же код.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (event.which>=48 && event.which=<57)
```

Зачем проверка на ctrl и shift?

Comment: В примере 

http://jsfiddle.net/zLmtco42/7/

Можно вводить надстрочные знаки, типа !@#$%^&*(), но нельзя пользоватся backspace. Нехорошо.